# raw html displayed instead of interpretation

Tags: html, jquery, css

When i run this code i get raw HTML as output. I expected just the text like the other two times. If i change the class name "grid-item" to something else it doesn´t show the second insert at all. How to make this precise code incision?

```
<div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    1
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    2
  </div>
</div> 

<div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    1
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    2
  </div>
</div>
```

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".grid-item:nth-child(1)").after(Element);
  $(".grid-item:nth-child(1)")[1].after(Element);
  
});
            
var Element = '<div class="grid-item"> problem text </div>';
```

output:

```
1
problem text
2
1
<div class="grid-item"> problem text </div>
problem text
2
```

Comment: What are you actually attempting to accomplish?

Comment: The problem is in this line: ```$(".grid-item:nth-child(1)")[1].after(Element);``` what is ```[1]``` ??? is this valid jQuery?

Comment: with $(".grid-item:nth-child(1)") i try to get a collection of the first .grid-items of their parent element. And with the number [1] i would like to just get a specific grid-item out of that collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `[1]` to `.eq(1)`.

When you subscript a jQuery collection, it returns the corresponding DOM element, not a jQuery object. Both jQuery and DOM elements have `.after()` methods, but they work differently. The jQuery method will interpret a string as HTML, while the DOM method treats it as text that should be rendered literally.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".grid-item:nth-child(1)").after(Element);
  $(".grid-item:nth-child(1)").eq(1).after(Element);

});

var Element = '<div class="grid-item"> problem text </div>';
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    1
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    2
  </div>
</div>

<div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    1
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    2
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that this is the code that you are looking for

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $(".grid-item:nth-child(1)").after(Element);
  $(".grid-item:nth-child(1)").eq(1).after(Element);
  
});
            
var Element = '<div class="grid-item"> problem text </div>';
```

There was `[1]` - it should be `.eq(1)` as above, according to you comment.